# html-webpack-plugin has no source file to refactor

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin, webpack-4

I am in the process of upgrading from webpack 3 to 4. The html-webpack-plugin is encountering

```
ERROR in Must have a source file to refactor.
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
     1 asset
    Entrypoint html-webpack-plugin for "index.html" = ./index.html
    [./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./pre-index.html] 1.91 KiB {html-webpack-plugin for "index.html"} [built]
Child html-webpack-plugin for "login.html":
     1 asset
    Entrypoint html-webpack-plugin for "login.html" = ./login.html
    [./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./pre-login.html] 5.31 KiB {html-webpack-plugin for "login.html"} [built]
? ?wdm?: Failed to compile.
```

It appears that it is trying to set the entrypoint to itself?

The webpack config file is huge, but here are the relevant parts

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: './pre-index.html',
    filename: outputIndexHtmlFile,
    hash: false,
    inject: true,
    compile: true,
    favicon: false,
    minify: false,
    cache: true,
    showErrors: true,
    chunks: 'all',
    excludeChunks: ['scripts-login', 'ng1'],
    title: 'Webpack App',
    xhtml: true,
    chunksSortMode: function sort(left, right) {
        const leftIndex = entryPoints.indexOf(left.names[0])
        const rightindex = entryPoints.indexOf(right.names[0])
        if (leftIndex > rightindex) {
            return 1
        } else if (leftIndex < rightindex) {
            return -1
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }
}),
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: './pre-login.html',
    filename: outputLoginHtmlFile,
    hash: false,
    inject: true,
    compile: true,
    favicon: false,
    minify: false,
    cache: true,
    showErrors: true,
    chunks: ['inline', 'ng1', 'scripts-login'],
    excludeChunks: [],
    title: 'Webpack App',
    xhtml: true,
    chunksSortMode: function sort(left, right) {
        const leftIndex = entryPointsLogin.indexOf(left.names[0])
        const rightindex = entryPointsLogin.indexOf(right.names[0])
        if (leftIndex > rightindex) {
            return 1
        } else if (leftIndex < rightindex) {
            return -1
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }
}),
```

```
module.exports = function(env) {
    return {
        mode:'development',
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
            modules: ['./node_modules', './node_modules']
        },
        resolveLoader: {
            modules: ['./node_modules', './node_modules']
        },
        entry: {
            main: ['./main.js', './ng2/main.ts'],
            polyfills: ['./ng2/polyfills.ts'],
            scripts: 'script-loader!./concat/concat.js',
            styles: ['./ng2/styles.scss'],
            ng1: './ng2/ng1.config.ts',
            'scripts-login': loginDependencies
        },
        output: {
            path: path.join(process.cwd(), 'dist'),
            filename: '[name].bundle.js',
            chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue. This is my updated webpack config file. I did not identify a specific resolution to the problem. In addition I updated all of my packages to the most current version. I wish I could provide a better answer.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
const ProgressPlugin = require('webpack/lib/ProgressPlugin')
const CircularDependencyPlugin = require('circular-dependency-plugin')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin')
const rxPaths = require('rxjs/_esm5/path-mapping')
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer')
const postcssUrl = require('postcss-url')
const postcssImports = require('postcss-import')
const loginDependencies = require('./login/scripts').map(dep => `script-loader!${dep}`)
const babelFiles = [path.join(process.cwd(), 'components/'), path.join(process.cwd(), 'services/'), path.join(process.cwd(), 'models/'), path.join(process.cwd(), 'ng1/'), path.join(process.cwd(), 'utils/'), path.join(process.cwd(), 'main.js')]

const { NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin, EnvironmentPlugin, HashedModuleIdsPlugin } = require('webpack')
const { BaseHrefWebpackPlugin, SuppressExtractedTextChunksWebpackPlugin, CleanCssWebpackPlugin, BundleBudgetPlugin, PostcssCliResources } = require('@angular/cli/plugins/webpack')
const { ModuleConcatenationPlugin } = require('webpack').optimize
// const { LicenseWebpackPlugin } = require('license-webpack-plugin')
const { PurifyPlugin } = require('@angular-devkit/build-optimizer')
const { AngularCompilerPlugin } = require('@ngtools/webpack')
const entryPointsLogin = ['inline', 'ng1', 'scripts-login']
const nodeModules = path.join(process.cwd(), 'node_modules')
const realNodeModules = fs.realpathSync(nodeModules)
const genDirNodeModules = path.join(process.cwd(), 'src', '$$_gendir', 'node_modules')
const entryPoints = ['inline', 'polyfills', 'sw-register', 'styles', 'vendor', 'main']
const hashFormat = {
    chunk: '.[chunkhash:20]',
    extract: '.[contenthash:20]',
    file: '.[hash:20]',
    script: '.[hash:20]'
}
const baseHref = ''
const deployUrl = ''
const projectRoot = process.cwd()
const maximumInlineSize = 10
const postcssPlugins = function(loader) {
    return [
        postcssImports({
            resolve: (url, context) => {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    let hadTilde = false
                    if (url && url.startsWith('~')) {
                        url = url.substr(1)
                        hadTilde = true
                    }
                    loader.resolve(context, (hadTilde ? '' : './') + url, (err, result) => {
                        if (err) {
                            if (hadTilde) {
                                reject(err)
                                return
                            }
                            loader.resolve(context, url, (err, result) => {
                                if (err) {
                                    reject(err)
                                } else {
                                    resolve(result)
                                }
                            })
                        } else {
                            resolve(result)
                        }
                    })
                })
            },
            load: filename => {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    loader.fs.readFile(filename, (err, data) => {
                        if (err) {
                            reject(err)
                            return
                        }
                        const content = data.toString()
                        resolve(content)
                    })
                })
            }
        }),
        postcssUrl({
            filter: ({ url }) => url.startsWith('~'),
            url: ({ url }) => {
                const fullPath = path.join(projectRoot, 'node_modules', url.substr(1))
                return path.relative(loader.context, fullPath).replace(/\\/g, '/')
            }
        }),
        postcssUrl([
            {
                // Only convert root relative URLs, which CSS-Loader won't process into require().
                filter: ({ url }) => url.startsWith('/') && !url.startsWith('//'),
                url: ({ url }) => {
                    if (deployUrl.match(/:\/\//) || deployUrl.startsWith('/')) {
                        // If deployUrl is absolute or root relative, ignore baseHref & use deployUrl as is.
                        return `${deployUrl.replace(/\/$/, '')}${url}`
                    } else if (baseHref.match(/:\/\//)) {
                        // If baseHref contains a scheme, include it as is.
                        return baseHref.replace(/\/$/, '') + `/${deployUrl}/${url}`.replace(/\/\/+/g, '/')
                    } else {
                        // Join together base-href, deploy-url and the original URL.
                        // Also dedupe multiple slashes into single ones.
                        return `/${baseHref}/${deployUrl}/${url}`.replace(/\/\/+/g, '/')
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                // TODO: inline .cur if not supporting IE (use browserslist to check)
                filter: asset => {
                    return maximumInlineSize > 0 && !asset.hash && !asset.absolutePath.endsWith('.cur')
                },
                url: 'inline',
                // NOTE: maxSize is in KB
                maxSize: maximumInlineSize,
                fallback: 'rebase'
            },
            {
                url: 'rebase'
            }
        ]),
        PostcssCliResources({
            deployUrl: loader.loaders[loader.loaderIndex].options.ident == 'extracted' ? '' : deployUrl,
            loader,
            filename: `[name]${hashFormat.file}.[ext]`
        }),
        autoprefixer({
            grid: true
        })
    ]
}

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
        symlinks: true,
        modules: ['./node_modules'],
        // alias: rxPaths(),
        mainFields: ['browser', 'module', 'main']
    },
    resolveLoader: {
        modules: ['./node_modules']
        // alias: rxPaths()
    },
    entry: {
        main: ['./main.js', './ng2/main.ts'],
        polyfills: ['./ng2/polyfills.ts'],
        scripts: 'script-loader!./concat/concat.js',
        styles: ['./ng2/styles.scss'],
        ng1: './ng2/ng1.config.ts',
        'scripts-login': loginDependencies
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(process.cwd(), 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
        // crossOriginLoading: false
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                enforce: 'pre',
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'source-map-loader',
                exclude: [/\/node_modules\//]
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'raw-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|svg|cur)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: '[name].[hash:20].[ext]',
                    limit: 10000
                }
            },

            {
                test: /\.(jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)$/,
                loader: 'url-loader',
                options: {
                    name: '[name].[hash:20].[ext]',
                    limit: 10000
                }
            },
            // {
            //     test: /\.js$/,
            //     use: [
            //         {
            //             loader: 'cache-loader',
            //             options: {
            //                 cacheDirectory: 'C:\\Workspace\\TEMP\\angular-cli-webpack4-sample\\node_modules\\@angular-devkit\\build-optimizer\\src\\.cache'
            //             }
            //         },
            //         {
            //             loader: '@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/webpack-loader',
            //             options: {
            //                 sourceMap: false
            //             }
            //         }
            //     ]
            // },
            {
                exclude: [path.join(process.cwd(), 'ng2/styles.scss')],
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'exports-loader?module.exports.toString()',
                    {
                        loader: 'raw-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader',
                        options: {
                            ident: 'embedded',
                            plugins: postcssPlugins,
                            sourceMap: false
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                exclude: [path.join(process.cwd(), 'src\\styles.css')],
                test: /\.scss$|\.sass$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'raw-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader',
                        options: {
                            ident: 'embedded',
                            plugins: postcssPlugins,
                            sourceMap: false
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: false,
                            precision: 8,
                            includePaths: []
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                exclude: [path.join(process.cwd(), 'src\\styles.css')],
                test: /\.less$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'raw-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader',
                        options: {
                            ident: 'embedded',
                            plugins: postcssPlugins,
                            sourceMap: false
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'less-loader',
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: false
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                exclude: [path.join(process.cwd(), 'src\\styles.css')],
                test: /\.styl$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'raw-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader',
                        options: {
                            ident: 'embedded',
                            plugins: postcssPlugins,
                            sourceMap: false
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'stylus-loader',
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: false,
                            paths: []
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                include: [path.join(process.cwd(), 'src\\styles.css')],
                test: /\.css$/,
                loaders: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'raw-loader'
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'postcss-loader',
                            options: {
                                ident: 'extracted',
                                plugins: postcssPlugins,
                                sourceMap: false
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    publicPath: ''
                })
            },
            {
                include: [path.join(process.cwd(), 'src\\styles.css')],
                test: /\.scss$|\.sass$/,
                loaders: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'raw-loader'
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'postcss-loader',
                            options: {
                                ident: 'extracted',
                                plugins: postcssPlugins,
                                sourceMap: false
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'sass-loader',
                            options: {
                                sourceMap: false,
                                precision: 8,
                                includePaths: []
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    publicPath: ''
                })
            },
            {
                include: [path.join(process.cwd(), 'src\\styles.css')],
                test: /\.less$/,
                loaders: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'raw-loader'
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'postcss-loader',
                            options: {
                                ident: 'extracted',
                                plugins: postcssPlugins,
                                sourceMap: false
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'less-loader',
                            options: {
                                sourceMap: false
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    publicPath: ''
                })
            },
            {
                include: [path.join(process.cwd(), 'src\\styles.css')],
                test: /\.styl$/,
                loaders: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'raw-loader'
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'postcss-loader',
                            options: {
                                ident: 'extracted',
                                plugins: postcssPlugins,
                                sourceMap: false
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'stylus-loader',
                            options: {
                                sourceMap: false,
                                paths: []
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    publicPath: ''
                })
            },
            {
                include: babelFiles,
                test: /\.(js)$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        babelrc: true
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /(?:\.ngfactory\.js|\.ngstyle\.js|\.ts)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: '@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/webpack-loader',
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: false
                        }
                    },
                    '@ngtools/webpack'
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin(
            [
                {
                    context: 'src',
                    to: '',
                    from: {
                        glob: 'assets\\**\\*',
                        dot: true
                    }
                },
                {
                    context: 'src',
                    to: '',
                    from: {
                        glob: 'favicon.ico',
                        dot: true
                    }
                }
            ],
            {
                ignore: ['.gitkeep', '**/.DS_Store', '**/Thumbs.db'],
                debug: 'warning'
            }
        ),
        new ProgressPlugin(),
        new CircularDependencyPlugin({
            exclude: /(\\|\/)node_modules(\\|\/)/,
            failOnError: false,
            onDetected: false,
            cwd: projectRoot
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './pre-index.html',
            filename: './index.html',
            hash: false,
            inject: true,
            compile: true,
            favicon: false,
            minify: false,
            cache: true,
            showErrors: true,
            chunks: 'all',
            excludeChunks: ['scripts-login', 'ng1'],
            title: 'Webpack App',
            xhtml: true,
            chunksSortMode: function sort(left, right) {
                const leftIndex = entryPoints.indexOf(left.names[0])
                const rightIndex = entryPoints.indexOf(right.names[0])
                if (leftIndex > rightIndex) {
                    return 1
                } else if (leftIndex < rightIndex) {
                    return -1
                } else {
                    return 0
                }
            }
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './pre-login.html',
            filename: './login.html',
            hash: false,
            inject: true,
            compile: true,
            favicon: false,
            minify: false,
            cache: true,
            showErrors: true,
            chunks: ['inline', 'ng1', 'scripts-login'],
            excludeChunks: [],
            title: 'Webpack App',
            xhtml: true,
            chunksSortMode: function sort(left, right) {
                const leftIndex = entryPointsLogin.indexOf(left.names[0])
                const rightIndex = entryPointsLogin.indexOf(right.names[0])
                if (leftIndex > rightIndex) {
                    return 1
                } else if (leftIndex < rightIndex) {
                    return -1
                } else {
                    return 0
                }
            }
        }),
        new BaseHrefWebpackPlugin({}),
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: '[name].[contenthash:20].bundle.css'
        }),
        new CleanCssWebpackPlugin(),
        new EnvironmentPlugin({
            NODE_ENV: 'production'
        }),
        new HashedModuleIdsPlugin({
            hashFunction: 'md5',
            hashDigest: 'base64',
            hashDigestLength: 4
        }),
        new ModuleConcatenationPlugin({}),
        new BundleBudgetPlugin({}),

        // new LicenseWebpackPlugin({
        //     licenseFilenames: ['LICENSE', 'LICENSE.md', 'LICENSE.txt', 'license', 'license.md', 'license.txt'],
        //     perChunkOutput: false,
        //     outputTemplate: path.join(process.cwd(), 'node_modules\\license-webpack-plugin\\output.template.ejs'),
        //     outputFilename: '3rdpartylicenses.txt',
        //     suppressErrors: true,
        //     includePackagesWithoutLicense: false,
        //     abortOnUnacceptableLicense: false,
        //     addBanner: false,
        //     bannerTemplate: '/*! 3rd party license information is available at <%- filename %> */',
        //     includedChunks: [],
        //     excludedChunks: [],
        //     additionalPackages: [],
        //     pattern: /^(MIT|ISC|BSD.*)$/
        // }),
        new PurifyPlugin(),
        new UglifyJsPlugin({
            test: /\.js$/i,
            extractComments: false,
            sourceMap: false,
            cache: true,
            parallel: true,
            uglifyOptions: {
                output: {
                    ascii_only: true,
                    comments: false,
                    webkit: true
                },
                ecma: 5,
                warnings: false,
                ie8: false,
                mangle: {
                    safari10: true
                },
                compress: {
                    typeofs: false,
                    pure_getters: true,
                    passes: 3
                }
            }
        }),
        new AngularCompilerPlugin({
            mainPath: 'main.ts',
            platform: 0,
            hostReplacementPaths: {
                'environments/environment.ts': `environments/environmentdevelopment.ts`
            },
            sourceMap: false,
            tsConfigPath: 'ng2/tsconfig.app.json',
            compilerOptions: {}
        })
    ],
    node: {
        fs: 'empty',
        global: true,
        crypto: 'empty',
        tls: 'empty',
        net: 'empty',
        process: true,
        module: false,
        clearImmediate: false,
        setImmediate: false
    },
    devServer: {
        compress: true,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        compress: true,
        proxy: {
            '/oms': {
                target: 'http://localhost:8080',
                bypass: function(req, res, proxyOptions) {
                    if (req && req.url) {
                        // console.log('current url', req.url);
                        if (req.url.indexOf('/oms/index.html') !== -1 || req.url === '/oms/') {
                            console.log('catched', req.url)
                            return '/index.html'
                        } else if (req.url.indexOf('/oms/login.html') !== -1) {
                            console.log('catched', req.url)
                            return '/login.html'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```